# Regex match digits with lookahead

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, lookbehind

I have a regex:

```
(\d{1,20})
```

Which matches:

```
JPY;       7112630;
```

In this string I want to catch only the digits: so I use: $1
But I also want to add ".00" after the digits so I use: $1.00

But now I also want to match the digits, only if I have JPY before.

I tried:

```
(?=JPY;\s*)(\d{1,20})
(?<=JPY;\s*)(\d{1,20})
```

No success!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a *capturing group* instead of the infinite-width  positive lookbehind:

```
(JPY;\s*\d{1,20})
```

And replace with `$1.00`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JTHOIK/2).

Depending on the regex engine, you may remove the `(...)` capturing parentheses, and use `$0` or `$&` instead of the `$1` in the replacement pattern.

Also, if you need to match these values as whole words, enclose with word boundaries: `\b(JPY;\s*\d{1,20})\b`.